# How to use Spring WebClient to make non-blocking calls and send email after all calls complete?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming, project-reactor, spring-webclient

I'm using Spring's 'WebClient` and project reactor to make non-blocking calls to a list of URLs. My requirements are:

1. Asynchronously call GET on a list of URLs
2. Log the URL when each URL is called
3. Log the URL of a call that results in a exception
4. Log the URL of a call that is successful
5. Log the URL of a call that results in a non 2xx HTTP status
6. Send an email containing a list of URLs where the call resulted in an exception or non 2xx HTTP status

Here's my attempt to do this:

```
List<Mono<ClientResponse>> restCalls = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> failedUrls = new ArrayList<>();    
for (String serviceUrl : serviceUrls.getServiceUrls()) {
        
        restCalls.add(
                webClientBuilder
                    .build()
                    .get()
                    .uri(serviceUrl)
                    .exchange()
                    .doOnSubscribe(c -> log.info("calling service URL {}", serviceUrl))
                    .doOnSuccess(response -> log.info("{} success status {}", serviceUrl, response.statusCode().toString()))
                    .doOnError(response -> {log.info("{} error status {}", serviceUrl, response); failedUrls.add(serviceUrl);}));
    }
    
    Flux.fromIterable(restCalls)
        .map((data) -> data.subscribe())
        .onErrorContinue((throwable, e) -> {
             
            log.info("Exception for URL {}", ((WebClientResponseException) throwable).getRequest().getURI());
          
            failedUrls.add(serviceUrl);
        })
        .collectList()
        .subscribe((data) -> {
            log.info("all called");
            email.send("Failed URLs are {}", failedUrls);
    });
```

The problem is the email is sent before the calls respond. How can I wait until all URLs calls have been completed prior to calling `email.send`?

Comment: You should at least replace `.map((data) -> data.subscribe())` with `.flatMap(data -> data)`, because subscribe triggers action, but does not allow to observe its result (the return value is only for cancelling launched job). Also, beware of onErrorContinue (more information[on this issue](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/2184)). I'll try to add a more extended answer later, but maybe these hints are enough for you to solve your problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in comment, the main error in your example is the use of 'subscribe', that launch queries, but in a context independant from the main flux, so you cannot get back errors or results.

subscribe is sort of a trigger operation on the pipeline, it's not used for chaining.

Here is a full example (except email, replaced by logging):

```java
package fr.amanin.stackoverflow;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class WebfluxURLProcessing {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("example");

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final List<String> urls = Arrays.asList("https://www.google.com", "https://kotlinlang.org/kotlin/is/wonderful/", "https://stackoverflow.com", "http://doNotexists.blabla");

        final Flux<ExchangeDetails> events = Flux.fromIterable(urls)
                // unwrap request async operations
                .flatMap(url -> request(url))
                // Add a side-effect to log results
                .doOnNext(details -> log(details))
                // Keep only results that show an error
                .filter(details -> details.status < 0 || !HttpStatus.valueOf(details.status).is2xxSuccessful());

        sendEmail(events);
    }

    /**
     * Mock emails by collecting all events in a text and logging it.
     * @param report asynchronous flow of responses
     */
    private static void sendEmail(Flux<ExchangeDetails> report) {
        final String formattedReport = report
                .map(details -> String.format("Error on %s. status: %d. Reason: %s", details.url, details.status, details.error.getMessage()))
                // collecting (or reducing, folding, etc.) allows to gather all upstream results to use them as a single value downstream.
                .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator(), "REPORT:"+System.lineSeparator(), ""))
                // In a real-world scenario, replace this with a subscribe or chaining to another reactive operation.
                .block();
        LOGGER.info(formattedReport);
    }

    private static void log(ExchangeDetails details) {
        if (details.status >= 0 && HttpStatus.valueOf(details.status).is2xxSuccessful()) {
            LOGGER.info("Success on: "+details.url);
        } else {
            LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING,
                    "Status {0} on {1}. Reason: {2}",
                    new Object[]{
                            details.status,
                            details.url,
                            details.error == null ? "None" : details.error.getMessage()
                    });
        }
    }

    private static Mono<ExchangeDetails> request(String url) {
        return WebClient.create(url).get()
                .retrieve()
                // workaround to counter fail-fast behavior: create a special error that will be converted back to a result
                .onStatus(status -> !status.is2xxSuccessful(), cr -> cr.createException().map(err -> new RequestException(cr.statusCode(), err)))
                .toBodilessEntity()
                .map(response -> new ExchangeDetails(url, response.getStatusCode().value(), null))
                // Convert back custom error to result
                .onErrorResume(RequestException.class, err -> Mono.just(new ExchangeDetails(url, err.status.value(), err.cause)))
                // Convert errors that shut connection before server response (cannot connect, etc.) to a result
                .onErrorResume(Exception.class, err -> Mono.just(new ExchangeDetails(url, -1, err)));
    }

    public static class ExchangeDetails {
        final String url;
        final int status;
        final Exception error;

        public ExchangeDetails(String url, int status, Exception error) {
            this.url = url;
            this.status = status;
            this.error = error;
        }
    }

    private static class RequestException extends RuntimeException {
        final HttpStatus status;
        final Exception cause;

        public RequestException(HttpStatus status, Exception cause) {
            this.status = status;
            this.cause = cause;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but this should work

```
public void check() {
    
    List<Flux<String>> restCalls = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for (String serviceUrl : serviceUrls.getServiceUrls()) {
        restCalls.add(rest.getForEntity(serviceUrl, String.class));
    }
    
   Flux.fromIterable(restCalls)
            .map((data) -> data.blockFirst())
            .onErrorContinue((throwable, e) -> {
                ((WebClientResponseException) throwable).getRequest().getURI(); // get the failing URI
                // do whatever you need with the failed service

            })
            .collectList() // Collects all the results into a list
            .subscribe((data) -> {
                // from here do whatever is needed from the results
            });
}
```

So if you haven't done so, your service call must be non blocking, so you should turn the type into Flux.
So inside your restService your method should be something like this

```
public Flux<String> getForEntity(String name) {
    return this.webClient.get().uri("url", name)
            .retrieve().bodyToFlux(String.class);
}
```

I hope it helps out

Comment: Thanks. But this `blockFirst` is not a valid method. When I change it to `block`, it blocks after each URL call. I want my URL calls to be non-blocking. Once all URLs return a response, then I want to send an email.

Answer (score 0):

```
            restCalls.add(
            webClientBuilder
                .build()
                .get()
                .uri(serviceUrl)
                .exchange()
                .doOnSubscribe(c -> log.info("calling service URL {}", serviceUrl))
                .doOnSuccess(response -> log.info("{} success status {}", serviceUrl, response.statusCode().toString()))
                .doOnError(response -> {log.info("{} error status {}", serviceUrl, response); failedUrls.add(serviceUrl);}));

                Flux.fromIterable(restCalls)
                .map((data) -> data.subscribe())
                .onErrorContinue((throwable, e) -> {
                 log.info("Exception for URL {}", ((WebClientResponseException)                       throwable).getRequest().getURI());
                 failedUrls.add(serviceUrl);
                 })
                .collectList()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())
                .subscribe((data) -> {
                log.info("all called");
                email.send("Failed URLs are {}", failedUrls);
                });
```